# can't connect android studio with firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am a newbie in android, i tried many times to connect with firebase but I can't do that with android studio, It always shows me that message. i searched for many solutions but nothing worked. i tried to put --stacktrace in compiler, command line options but it also didn't work.

thnx in advance.

this is what it says:

`Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  CONFIGURE FAILED in 26s
  Could not find method platform() for arguments [com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
  `

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu5MK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code in your `buildl.gradle` `Module:Your_app_name` file

```
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
```

And have you added `google-services.json` file in your project?

Comment: these two lines are already added there, and the json file as well. what else can i do to solve this?.

Comment: By looking at your error it seems that you're using 26.5 and this is beta version maybe so put 26.4 there